# How to use an if statement to filter records from a model object ror

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-4

I have service and servicebooking models, I want to view the current users made servicebookings by checking the owner_id attribute in the servicebooking model.

My servicebooking controller method:

```
def myservicebookings
  if current_user.id == @servicebooking.owner_id
    @servicebookings = current_user.servicebookings.search(params[:search]).order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction).paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page])
  else
    "You have no service bookings"
  end
end
```

My servicebookings view:

```
<% if current_user.id == @servicebooking.owner_id %><% @servicebookings.each do |servicebooking| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= servicebooking.date %></td>
      <td><%= servicebooking.time %></td>
      <td><%= servicebooking.service_name %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
  <% else %>
  <%= "You have no outgoing service bookings" %>
  <% end %>
```

Currently I get the following error when trying to load the myservicebookings form:

undefined method `owner_id' for nil:NilClass

Any ideas on how to change this code to make it work? thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 1):

You should switch the position of the loop and and if statement in your view, then use the loop variable`servicebooking` not the instance variable `@servicebooking`, making it look like this

```
<% @servicebookings.each do |servicebooking| %>
  <% if current_user.id == servicebooking.owner_id %>
     the rest of the view ...
```

**UPDATE**: If you want to update on the controller level, then it's almost the same:

```
@servicebookings = current_user.servicebookings.search(params[:search]).order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction).paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page])
@servicebookings.select! { |servicebooking| servicebooking.owner_id == current_user.id }
```

Comment: Hey Ahmed thanks for your answer, I have moved this if statement into the myservicebookings controller method and I get the same error: undefined method `owner_id' for nil:NilClass - The if statement worked in the view as per your instruction but was returning all the servicebookings including the ones that matched the owner id, so I wanted to filter at controller level, please see my edited question and let me know if you have tips? Thanks in advance

Comment: I can't see the updates in your question, would you please check again and post snippet of the updated controller?

Comment: Again, you're using an instance variable `@servicebooking` that's not defined, hence the error. If you want to filter in the controller then you would need to move the loop to the controller as well. Please see the updated answer for a code example. On the other hand, it would be more helpful if you posted the model with its table schema.

Comment: Hey Ahmad have you got an example of how I should use the loop in the controller with the .select! method and how the view should look? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

in you case, you dont need if statment because in this variable you have all current user servicebooking:

```
def myservicebookings
  @servicebookings = current_user.servicebookings.
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^ search(params[:search]).
                                  order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction).
                                  paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page])
end
```

use this:

```
<% if @servicebookings.any? %>
<% @servicebookings.each do |servicebooking| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= servicebooking.date %></td>
      <td><%= servicebooking.time %></td>
      <td><%= servicebooking.service_name %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <%= "You have no outgoing service bookings" %>
<% end %>
```

or this:

```
<% if @servicebookings.any? %>
<% for servicebooking in @servicebookings %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= servicebooking.date %></td>
      <td><%= servicebooking.time %></td>
      <td><%= servicebooking.service_name %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end if current_user.id == servicebooking.owner_id %>
<% else %>
  <%= "You have no outgoing service bookings" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: +1 For the use of .any? -> if accessible_attributes.any? -> If I have any accessible attributes.
ruby > [false, false, false, nil, nil].any?
 => false

Answer (score 0):

I would not mess with my views or my controller. I would go OOPS here. In RoR, its skinny controllers, fat models.

Goto your model,

```
class ServiceBooking < ActiveRecord::Base

  # u = User, srch = params[:search],p = params[:page],p_p = per_page,s_c =sort_columns, s_d = sort_direction
  def self.mine(u,srch,s_c,s_d,p,p_p = 5)
    u.servicebookings.search(srch).order(s_c + " " + s_d).paginate(per_page: p_p, page: => p)
  end

end
```

In your controller,

```
def myservicebookings
  # 6th argument to this method is overridable.
  @mine = ServiceBooking.mine(current_user,params[:search],sort_column,sort_direction,params[:page])    
end
```

In your View,

```
<% @mine.each do |m| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= m.date %></td>
      <td><%= m.time %></td>
      <td><%= m.service_name %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This logic looks fine, but I don't think it will check whether a user owns the service booking itself